# How to use Python to change file format without corrupting the file?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to use Python to convert an .xlsx file into a .txt file, but the resulting file is corrupt. When I manually open the .xlsx file and use File>Save as>.txt the file is fine. How can I convert the file with Python without corrupting it?

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Users/name/Desktop/Template.xlsx')
wb.save('/Users/name/Desktop/Template.upd.txt')
```

Comment: Nothing is "corrupt", but openpyxl doesn't export text files. Giving the output file a ".txt" extension doesn't accomplish anything; it still writes an Excel file, not a text file.

Comment: what delimiter is being used in xlsx

Answer (score 0):

You can write the sheet in a csv, but use tab as delimeter.
With pandas this should work. More details on these functions are in [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) and [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("yourexcel.xlsx",sheet_name="yoursheet",header=0)
df.to_csv("yourtxt.txt",sep="\t")
```